# Cucumber module integration

Tags: cucumber

We have several modules,each of these modules has separate cucumber test suite written. Now the goal is to connect these cucumber test suites to provide end to end module automated testing

Existing module setup

Module A

```
> Feature > Step definition (create xml file,validate xml attributes and post it to queue A)
```

Module B

```
> Feature > Step definition (publish static xml to queue A,verify various checkpoints,post message to queue B)
```

Module C

```
> Feature > Step definition (publish static xml to queue B,verify various check points,post message to queue C)
```

I started creating new Integration maven project

Integration project pom.xml has dependency on

```
1. Module A cucumber jar
2. Module B cucumber jar
3. Module C cucumber jar
```

> Integration Feature

```
Given all prerequisites
When message is posted from module A to queue A
Then verify the if message is published successfully to queue A
Then verify if module B consumed message from queue A, processed then posted message to queue B
Then verify if module C consumes message from queue B, processed then posted msg to queue C  
.....
...so on
```

> Integration Steps

```
@When
message is posted from module A to queue A {
    invoke steps def in module A jar to post the message (reuse step def method in module A)
}

@When 

    verify the if message is published successfully to queue A{
        invoke steps on module A jar and assert data (code reuse)
    }

@When 

    verify if module B consumed message from queue A, processed then posted message to queue B{
        invoke step def in module B jar and assert data (code reuse)
    }
```

Process Flow

```
>Integration Feature 
      >Integration Steps
         >IntegrationService Layer
            > Module A Service Layer
                > Invokes module A steps def 
                   1 Steps def
                   2 Steps def 
            > Module B Service Layer
                > Invokes module B steps def 
                    1 Steps def 
                    2 Steps def
```

Any suggestions or comments on integration design approach ? even better design approach are welcome

Answer (score 0):

in **CucumberOptions** you **use a list in glue parameter** with all path of package

```
@CucumberOptions(... glue = { "com.modulea.steps", "com.moduleb.steps", "com.modulec.steps" } ...}
```